# WordPress 4.0.1 Tab Title displays wrong

Tags: wordpress

I am using WordPress 4.0.1 and having a issue since updating to WordPress 4.0.1.

Before updating it was displaying fine but now I have a small issue and can't seen to work out where to look to fix this issue.

If I use **[tab title = “title one”]**

It displays

**“title**

Where before it would display it as **title one**

Anyone know where in WordPress I need to look to fix this ?

Comment: google wp shortcodes, it could be set anywhere in your theme or plugin.

Comment: do you mind sharing what theme you're using? i'm having this same problem

Comment: Replace left and right double quotation marks ( &ldquo; &rdquo; ) with real double quotation marks ( &quot; ).