# Tabs on website broken by Wordpress 4.0.1 update?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm having the same problem as mentioned in this question: [WordPress 4.0.1 Tab Title displays wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337758/wordpress-4-0-1-tab-title-displays-wrong) I thought I'd make my own question because I have a little more information than the asker of that question provided.

Here's the PHP for the tabs:

```
    $output = '<ul class="tabs">';
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $matches[0] ); $i++) {
        if ( $history == 'true' ) {
            $href = '#' . rawurlencode( str_replace( array( ' ', '.' ), array( '-', '' ), trim( $matches[3][$i]['title'] ) ) );
        } else {
            $href = '#';
        }
        $output .= '<li><a href="' . $href . '">' . $matches[3][$i]['title'] . '</a></li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';
```

which outputs this HTML as displayed on this page http://souffle.mothemes.com/shortcodes/accordions/ :

```
 <ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="#%26%238221%3BLorem%26%238221%3B" class="current">”Lorem”</a></li>
  <li><a href="#%26%238221%3BIpsum%26%238221%3B">”Ipsum”</a></li>
  <li><a href="#%26%238221%3BDolor%26%238221%3B">”Dolor”</a></li>
 </ul>
```

The reverse quotes shouldn't be there, and for titles longer than one word, only the first word displays.

I can't for the life of me figure out where the problem comes from. The options seem to be:

1. the PHP listed above
2. the backend dialogue that requests the information for the PHP
3. the Javascript file that connects the two (?? my Javascript is very, very, very limited.)

And I have no idea why the Wordpress 4.0.1 update would have broken this (I took a look at the changelog but I don't know enough to really know what I'm looking for).

Any help here would be appreciated since I am entirely lost on my own.

Thanks!

Comment: WordPress / PHP won't randomly add HTML entities such as `&#8221;`. What is the result of `var_dump($matches)`?

Comment: Is this shortcode from a plugin or theme? I think that the problem could be in attribute value, since WP accepts values enclosed in single or double quotes, or no quotes if value does not contain spaces, but this value looks like starts and ends with &#8221; HTML entity.